# Leaflet map: map container is already initialized

Tags: javascript, json

I am a begineer and have a problem reloading a map with already set coordinates. I used fetch to pull data from an APi, then I put the data in the map. It shows an error: Map is already initialized!

```
const fetchPosts = async () => {
  fetch("https://itk-exam-api.herokuapp.com/api/offices")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((posts) => {
      console.log(posts);
      return getPosition(posts);
    });
};


const getPosition = (posts) => {
  posts.forEach((post) => {
    latitude = post.latitude;
    longitude = post.longitude;
    const coords = [latitude, longitude];
    console.log (coords);

    const mymap = L.map('map').setView(coords, 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(mymap);


    L.marker(coords).addTo(mymap)
      .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
      .openPopup();
  });
}

fetchPosts();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L.map('map')` initializes a Leaflet map using the given element id. You cannot call this twice for the same element.

```js
const attribution = document.querySelector("#attribution").innerHTML;
const mymap = L.map("map").setView([0, 0], 0);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution })
  .addTo(mymap);
  
L.map("mymap"); // <- error, the map is already initalized
```

```css
#map { height: 70px; }
```

```html
<link crossorigin rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<template id="attribution">
  &copy;
  <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">
    OpenStreetMap
  </a>
  contributors
</template>
```

Instead of initializing the Leaflet map as part of the `getPosition()` function you could reference the map via a variable that is in scope, or pass the map through the parameters.

```js
// initialize the map a single time
const attribution = document.querySelector("#attribution").innerHTML;
const mymap = L.map("map").setView([0, 0], 0);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution })
  .addTo(mymap);

async function fetchPosts() {
  const response = await fetch("https://itk-exam-api.herokuapp.com/api/offices");
  const posts = await response.json();
  getPosition(posts);
}

function getPosition(posts) {
  posts.forEach((post) => {
    const coords = [post.latitude, post.longitude];
    
    // Reference the Leaflet map that is already initialized (mymap),
    // instead of trying to re-initialize a new Leaflet map on the same
    // container.

    L.marker(coords).addTo(mymap)
      .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
      .openPopup();
  });
}

fetchPosts()
  .catch(console.error);
```

```css
#map { height: 180px; }
```

```html
<link crossorigin rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<template id="attribution">
  &copy;
  <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">
    OpenStreetMap
  </a>
  contributors
</template>
```